# Nginx always not resolving path using $server_name with try_files

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have the following location configuration as part of a reverse proxy server:

```
error_page 503 502 @down;
location @down {
  try_files /error/test/$server_name.html /error/test/generic.html;
  internal;
}
location /error/ {
  root /usr/share/nginx/html/;
  internal;
}
```

For a server block with server_name of events.example.com, I would expect `/usr/share/nginx/html/error/test/events.example.com.html` to be served if it exists. Otherwise Nginx should serve `/usr/share/nginx/html/error/test/generic.html`.

Nginx is always displaying the `generic.html` page, even when the more specific page exists. I thought that it might be that the variable wasn't being evaluated, so I created a file called `$server_name.html` in the error directory. The problem still persisted. If I change the try_files line to

```
index /error/test/$server_name.html
```

the configuration works as expected.

How can I have Nginx resolve a file based on the $server_name variable and fallback to a generic file if the first file does not exist?

Comment: What's wrong with the solution you already gave?

Comment: My guess, you should use `$host` variable instead. `$server_name` is usually not what people thing it is.

Comment: I agree with Alexey Ten. If that location block is within a catch-all server block then you should use $host instead of $server_name because the latter is going to be an empty string.

Comment: The location is being included in every server block. I suppose I could make a catch all, but I don't actually want this to catch everything. I have a production environment which should show maintenance pages (using an almost identical configuration), and the test environment which uses the configuration above. They are both being served from the same nginx reverse proxy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `root` statement is not in scope when the `try_files` statement is encountered. So `nginx` cannot determine the correct path to the file.

Also, `try_files` will process the *file* terms within the same `location`, so you could combine both locations into a single named `location` (assuming that `location /error/ { ... }` is not required elsewhere).

For example:

```
error_page 503 502 @down;
location @down {
  root /usr/share/nginx/html/;
  try_files /error/test/$server_name.html /error/test/generic.html =404;
}
```

Add the `=404` so that the second parameter is treated as a *file* parameter and not a *URI* parameter. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for more.

Comment: It looks like the out of scope root statement was the issue. I tried placing the error location block above and it didn't change anything, but when I placed the root statement inside the @down location block, the page works as expected. I'm only using the /error/  location in two places, so I don't mind the duplication.

Comment: Ah, that documentation for try_files explains what was happening. Since nginx couldn't find the requested files (because the root statement was out of scope), then it deferred to the last parameter, which was treated as a uri and did an internal redirect. The /error/ location caught the redirect and displayed the page. If I had a code at the end originally this would have been a lot less confusing